# Organizando herança de formulários - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, herança

Estou fazendo um programa pra venda de produtos e tô com um problema de design. O diferencial desse programa é que ele pode assumir duas caras diferentes: uma para venda de chocolates e outra para venda de frutas. Os formulários eu organizei mais ou menos dessa forma:

[image]
Organizei desse jeito pra que eu conseguisse copiar o comportamento dos formulários base, já que eles são exatamente iguais nesse ponto e só mudam visualmente.

O problema é que os controles de um formulário nem sempre são os mesmos de outro. Por exemplo, um botão de **Voltar** no modo de chocolates é um `Button`, mas no de frutas é uma `PictureBox`, por isso eu preciso associá-los de alguma forma ao comportamento do formulário base.
Pensei em colocar propriedades do tipo `Control` nos formulários base e aí eu só faria a associação em cada formulário, mas parece que vai ficar meio bagunçado, já que eu também teria que fazer o registro dos eventos `Click` manualmente. Não tenho muita confiança de que vai ficar fácil de manter.

Alguém já tentou fazer alguma coisa parecida e tem alguma dica?

Comment: Por que você não faz uma classe intermediária e implementa apenas o evento de `click`?

Comment: Você pode declarar o botão de voltar como sendo de um tipo base comum entre os botões dos dois formulários. Daí você adiciona o botão no formulário em um evento de tempo de execução, buscando a instância do botão em uma propriedade virtual implementada por cada formulário filho. De qualquer modo herança de formulário é muito trabalhoso e difícil de dar manutenção (como qualquer outra herança, na verdade). Eu procuraria alternativas mais simples.

Comment: Como assim, jbueno?

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma pesquisada e descobri a MVP Pattern. Acho que vai servir perfeitamente pra esse projeto. No caso, ficaria assim, creio eu:

[image]
Se alguém quiser dar uma lida sobre: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874262/mvp-framework-for-winforms